# When I connect to a remote database from a Docker container, what IP address does the remote see?

Tags: docker, subnet

I have Docker containers which use a `bridge` network with `subnet 172.16.238.0/24` and I'm connecting to external databases.  *(Successfully.)*

What I'd like to know, though, is:  *what IP address* does the remote database see the connection as coming from?  Does it see an address in the subnet address range on any of the packets that it receives?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a remote server, it will see the public IP of the host, which is running the docker container/docker service.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, thank you Husein ... I'll call it "answered."

The reason for my question is that I'm getting an unexpected security-error from an AS/400 DB2 database when I think I'm giving it the right password.  I just wanted to make sure that a `172.16.238.xxx` IP-address wasn't showing up in any of the internal fields of the packet that the remote database might be examining.  *(Naturally, this database is well-protected.)*  I'll follow up with the friendly DBA's now ... and if they say anything interesting I'll add it to this or another ticket.